# .htaccess redirect for index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this code on my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ decode.php
```

When I go to `www.my_website/index` the `decode.php` is called

However, when I go to `www.my_website` , the `decode.php` is not called.

`decode.php` is just used to load header and footer.

Comment: what do you want to reach? help me help ypu

Comment: www.my_website/index and www.my_website are the same. However, I can't trigger the decode.php when I go to www.my_website

Comment: Do you have access to tour virtualhost? if so. What is in that file. Maybe you can use DirectoryIndex. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html. How is AllowOverride setup? Please clarify some more.

Comment: I know but as you said `decode.php` is used for header and footer and I think you should use 'include' for that.

Comment: @msiso  is correct. I you want other files to be loaded use include or require. I you want a different directoryindex use the configuration.

Comment: Yes as I said tell us what is your goal.

Comment: decode.php is used so that when a new page is created, footer and header are automatically included. I don't have to to to each page and type include. The footer and header loaded fine for all the page on my website except for the default www.my_website. For some reasons, the decode.php is not called

Comment: I need a fix for this line RewriteRule ^(.*)$ decode.php

Comment: so you are saying that you have no problem when you are not using `.htaccess` in all pages except `www.domain.com` and you had add `.htaccess` for solving `www.domain.com` problem? or you just want the code you wrote to work for `www.domain.com` as well?

Comment: In your .htaccess file try to add
DirectoryIndex decode.php index.php

Comment: I want my code to work on www.domain.com as well. cuz right no it doesn't work

Comment: @DanyHenriquez is right

Comment: I put DirectoryIndex decode.php and it fixed the issuse. Thanks

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Comment: @DanyHenriquez you can answer my question and I will mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file try to add DirectoryIndex decode.php index.php